# Separate area code from phone with HIVEQL

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a table with DDD and Phone fields. Some were registered correctly, others the ddd is next to the phone and I need to separate.

my table:

[image]

Modified table:

[image]

I am starting my studies in HIVEQL, how can I make this change?

Comment: please describe the algorithm, and why there is extra 00, null row?

Comment: @leftjoin 00 is just a demonstration.

I get a column with numbers:

Comment: 55 12 997000000 or 12 997000000 or null

Comment: Are those Brazil ddd codes? If you know the rules, please explain in detail how it should be parsed

Comment: In some cases, the field comes with Country DDI +55 and in other cases, the DDI doesn't come

Answer (score 1):

Use `regexp_extract(str, regex, group_number)` to extract ddd and telefone.  Demo:

```
with mytable as (--test data
select stack(3,'5566997000000','5521997000001','24997000011') as str
)

select regexp_extract(str,'^(?:55)?(\\d{2})(\\d+)',1) as ddd,
       regexp_extract(str,'^(?:55)?(\\d{2})(\\d+)',2) as telefone
from mytable
```

Result:

```
ddd telefone
66  997000000
21  997000001
24  997000011
```

Regexp `'^(?:55)?(\\d{2})(\\d+)'` meaning:

`^`        - beginning of the string anchor

`(?:55)?`  - non-capturing group with 55 country code zero or one time (optional)

`(\\d{2})` - capturing group with two digits - ddd

`(\\d+)`   - capturing group with 1+ digits - telefone